# DataTables and moment.js not sorting by date correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the information on https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18 to make DataTables sort a column of dates which are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, e.g. `11/10/2018` (representing 11th October 2018).

I have included the following scripts - in this order:

- jquery.dataTables.1.10.7.min.js (locally hosted)
- //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js
- moment.js (version 2.10.3, locally hosted)

My DataTables initialisation looks like this, as per the information on the URL above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'd/m/Y' );

    $('#coursesTable').DataTable({"searching": false
    });
});
```

But when I click the date heading in my `#coursesTable` it gives the following output:

[image]

Obviously this is wrong because if the dates are ordered chronologically - most recent first - then `06/09/2017` should appear before `07/08/2017` - but that's not the order they appear in.

When ordering them the other way (oldest first) it gives the same error - i.e. the order is still incorrect:

[image]

I can't understand why this is occurring?

Comment: Did you tried `$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dd/MM/YYYY' );`

Comment: You should provide an example of the data you are using, and/or how you initialize the DataTable.

Comment: The initialization code is there @davidkonrad. The data is rendered on page load via a PHP script and it simply outputs the date as shown - e.g. `06/02/2017`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is really vague, but you still need to define the column `type`:

```
columnDefs: [{
  target: 0, //index of column
  type: 'datetime-moment'
}]
```

And as @DavidCzadilek comment, you need use another date format `$.fn.dataTable.moment('D/M/YYYY')` (the suggested `DD/MM/YYYY` will **not** work)

**http://jsfiddle.net/xmhn4wpj/**

Comment: or use `columns.render` or `columnDefs.render` (see Docs for [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) and also [Column Rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)) like `render: function ( data, type, row ) {return moment(data).format('d/m/Y');}` by supplying any valid `date` string (like `YYYY-MM-DD` directly from SQL) that `momentjs` accepts.

Comment: adding type is wrong. See https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38315/datetime-moment-ordering-not-working

Comment: @GregBologna, It is **not** wrong but actually the correct approach for the given example.  It is "wrong" (or redundant) to force the dataType **if** you have only good data, but indeed the only thing you can do if you have bad data like `null` values and so on. This is the case not only with "moment dates", but with any default type like number, string, date, percentage and so on....

Comment: I already thought I had my code working, but either I broke it or didn't test it well enough.  I had "columnDefs: [{ target: 3, render: DataTable.render.datetime('MM-DD-YYYY') }]" but was missing: type: 'datetime-moment',  --> adding that in fixed my date sorting. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try to change the format to this, according to [Moment.js Documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

`$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );`

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f275sa1/

As suggested by @davidkonrad, columnDefs are not needed. And 'DD/MM/YYYY' is the correct format in this case, because the question uses days and months with leading zeroes.

Comment: Changing from "dd/MM/yyyy" (the C# en-gb locale format) to "DD/MM/YYYY" was what worked for me.